# Change Input to Upper Case

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS:

```
<script type="text/css">
$(function() {
    $('#upper').keyup(function() {
        this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="search">
        <input type="radio" name="table" class="table" value="professor" tabindex="1" /> Professor
        <input type="radio" name="table" class="table" value="department" tabindex="2" /> Department
        <input type="radio" name="table" id="upper" class="table" value="course" tabindex="3" /> Course
        <input type="text" name="search" class="keywords" value="Select an option..." onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?':this.value;" tabindex="4"  />
        <div id="content"> </div>
    </div>
```

Why is this still not working?? Just trying to call div ".keywords" from JS.

Comment: I wish I had time to put what I believe is the best answer here. It's to handle the keypress event and change the keycode to upper case if applicable, it's easier than it sounds to make cross browser compatible, but I think it's the best solution.

Comment: Actually the solution I was thinking of only works for IE... e.which is readonly in FF and WebKit, but IE lets you change e.keyCode. Try this in IE http://jsfiddle.net/48fSq/1/

Answer (score 279, accepted):

I think the most elegant way is without any javascript but with css. You can use [`text-transform: uppercase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) (this is inline just for the idea):

```
<input id="yourid" style="text-transform: uppercase" type="text" />
```

**Edit:**

So, in your case, if you want keywords to be uppercase change:
`keywords: $(".keywords").val(),` to `$(".keywords").val().toUpperCase(),`

Comment: @Tim - You're not allowed to have end tag's for INPUTs: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-INPUT

Comment: will the user input really be uppercase or is it just for display here ?

Comment: Need to keep in mind that retrieving the value using (just) JavaScript will return the original text; i.e. not uppercase. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/NWS6J/2/)

Comment: It doesn't look it will actually work to transform the actual value using CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/bdktb/

Comment: Yeah it doesnt work guys (and any gals), see updated html. Anyone have other alternative?? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Tim: Like BiAiB, you're [not assigning the uppercased text to anything](http://jsfiddle.net/avV2h/). Also, creating the jQuery object out of `this` is wasteful.

Comment: @user700070: That's a radio button. What on earth does it mean to make a radio button uppercase, and how can a user type into it?

Comment: You are right guys, i edited the answer, this should be right.

Comment: If you just want it to look upper-case, than this may be true. However, if you want the actual input.value to be upper case, you'll have to duplicate your efforts before submitting the form, or using input.value, which makes it not so elegant.

Comment: @Tim: You're _still_ not assigning the result of `toUpperCase()` to anything. "[The toUpperCase method returns the value of the string converted to uppercase. toUpperCase does not affect the value of the string itself.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)"

Comment: Yeah im looking for it to transform the value, since when typed the values in the db ARE in upper case form, therefore typing lower-case doesnt find anything. Anyone???

Comment: This simple idea just saved me from the fiery depths of event interaction witch's brew hell. May the system fan wind be always at your back,
May the heat sink shine warm upon your face.

Comment: @Tim: You should edit your answer from `toUpperCase` to `toLocaleUpperCase`, otherwise this will only convert a subset of the letters for most languages.

Answer (score 58):

Javascript string objects have a `toLocaleUpperCase()` function that makes the conversion itself easy.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/HwTEj/) of live capitalisation:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').keyup(function() {
        this.value = this.value.toLocaleUpperCase();
    });
});
```

---

Unfortunately, this resets the textbox contents completely, so the user's caret position (if not "the end of the textbox") is lost.

You can [hack this back in](http://jsfiddle.net/BfX2B/), though, with some browser-switching magic:

```
// Thanks http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea/
function getCaretPosition(ctrl) {
    var CaretPos = 0;    // IE Support
    if (document.selection) {
        ctrl.focus();
        var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
        Sel.moveStart('character', -ctrl.value.length);
        CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
    }
    // Firefox support
    else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0') {
        CaretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;
    }

    return CaretPos;
}

function setCaretPosition(ctrl, pos) {
    if (ctrl.setSelectionRange) {
        ctrl.focus();
        ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
    }
    else if (ctrl.createTextRange) {
        var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', pos);
        range.moveStart('character', pos);
        range.select();
    }
}


// The real work

$(function() {
    $('input').keyup(function() {
        // Remember original caret position
        var caretPosition = getCaretPosition(this);

        // Uppercase-ize contents
        this.value = this.value.toLocaleUpperCase();

        // Reset caret position
        // (we ignore selection length, as typing deselects anyway)
        setCaretPosition(this, caretPosition);
    });
});
```

---

Ultimately, it might be easiest to fake it. Set the style `text-transform: uppercase` on the textbox so that it *appears* uppercase to the user, then in your Javascript apply the text transformation once whenever the user's caret focus leaves the textbox entirely:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="keywords" class="uppercase" />
```

CSS:

```
input.uppercase { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').focusout(function() {
        // Uppercase-ize contents
        this.value = this.value.toLocaleUpperCase();
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 didn't thought of the loss of selection problem (and loss of cursor too). And it's so annoying when it happens.

this is the best answer to me

Comment: @Tomalak - In the first example, why not use focusout?

Comment: @Jared: I have made the assumption that the OP wants the textbox contents to automatically be uppercased _as the user types_. I certainly would.

Comment: @Tomalak - Yeesh. So much simpler to modify on focusout... But that is the first sentence. I'd at least make the argument, but this isn't my answer, so it's just a comment. :)

Comment: @Jared: Yes it is. It's also simpler to cook a barbeque than to write websites, but oh well, the aim is to write websites so that's what must be done!

Comment: @Jared: Oh, but combining `focusout` with `text-transform` is a good idea; thanks!

Comment: I tried implementing this, what is wrong here? See updated ^ puhleez :)

Comment: @user700070: You're still trying to do all this on the "course" input field, which is a radio button not a text field. It makes no sense. Don't you mean to apply it to the "keywords" field?

Comment: Wont that apply that to every input?

Comment: @user700070: Yes. Make the selector whatever you need it to be. In this case, possibly `$('input[name="keywords"]')`.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit your approach is nice i.e text-transform: uppercase; But It represents only at client view. when the content pass at server side it will lower case. Any idea?

Comment: @SJnawali The problem is that you didn't read the _whole_ answer. `text-transform: uppercase` is for during typing; the value is then overwritten with its uppercase equivalent when focus leaves the control.

Comment: You can replace `ctrl.selectionStart == '0'` with `ctrl.selectionStart === 0`.

Answer (score 13):

If you purpose it to a **html input**,
you can easily do this without the use of JavaScript! or any other JS libraries.
It would be standard and very easy to use a CSS tag **text-transform**:

```
<input type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase" >
```

or you can use a bootstrap class named as "text-uppercase"

```
<input type="text" class="text-uppercase" >
```

In this manner, your code is much simpler!

Answer (score 11):

Solutions using value.toUpperCase seem to have the problem that typing text into the field resets the cursor position to the end of the text. Solutions using text-transform seem to have the problem that the text submitted to the server is still potentially lowercase. This solution avoids those problems:

```js
function handleInput(e) {
   var ss = e.target.selectionStart;
   var se = e.target.selectionEnd;
   e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
   e.target.selectionStart = ss;
   e.target.selectionEnd = se;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtTest" oninput="handleInput(event)" />
```

Answer (score 9):

Can also do it this way but other ways seem better, this comes in handy if you only need it the once.

```
onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"
```

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
$('#search input.keywords').bind('change', function(){
    //this.value.toUpperCase();
    //EDIT: As  Mike Samuel suggested, this will be more appropriate for the job
    this.value = this.value.toLocaleUpperCase();
} );
```

Comment: You need to assign the result somewhere, and this won't work as the user types as `change` only fires when the control loses focus.

Comment: For user input, `.toLocaleUpperCase` is probably more appropriate.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleUpperCase

Comment: @Mike Samuel You're true, I didnt know that method. Hope it is cross browers, since I saw it on Msdn, i'll update my answer

Comment: @BiAiB: [This is broken](http://jsfiddle.net/WPMhk/); you are not assigning the uppercase version of the text to anything.

Comment: @user700070: It does, but it only takes effect when the textbox loses focus.

Comment: @user700070  maybe you'd prefer the 'keyup' event instead of the 'change'. look Tomalak Geret'kal 's solution for more

Comment: @BiAiB, `toLocaleUpperCase` is available cross-browser but it's behavior is not necessarily identical across different browser in the same locale as it obviously depends on the version of the character mappings present on the local machine.  It's specified in section 15.5.4.17 of the EcmaScript language standard.  cheers, mike

Comment: jQuery's `.bind()` has been deprecated since this answer, use `.change( function () { ... } );` instead now.

Answer (score 4):

I think the most easiest way to do is by using Bootstrap's class [".text-uppercase"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-transform)

```
<input type="text" class="text-uppercase" />
```

Comment: How is this different from other answers?

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find the text-uppercase in Bootstrap referred to in one of the answers. No matter, I created it;

```
.text-uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

This displays text in uppercase, but the underlying data is not transformed in this way.
So in jquery I have;

```
$(".text-uppercase").keyup(function () {
    this.value = this.value.toLocaleUpperCase();
});
```

This will change the underlying data wherever you use the text-uppercase class.

Answer (score 2):

```
onBlur="javascript:{this.value = this.value.toUpperCase(); }
```

will change uppercase easily.

[Demo Here](http://www-k12.atmos.washington.edu/~ovens/javascript/jseg28.html)

Answer (score 0):

This answer has a problem:

```
style="text-transform: uppercase"
```

it also converts the place holder word to upper case which is inconvenient

```
placeholder="first name"
```

when rendering the input, it writes "first name" placeholder as uppercase

```
FIRST NAME
```

so i wrote something better:

```
onkeypress="this.value = this.value + event.key.toUpperCase(); return false;"
```

it works good!, but it has some side effects if your javascript code is complex,

hope it helps somebody to give him/her an idea to develop a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="name" data-upper type="text"/>
<input id="middle" data-upper type="text"/>
<input id="sur" data-upper type="text"/>
```

> Upper the text on dynamically created element which has attribute
>   upper and when keyup action happens

```
$(document.body).on('keyup', '[data-upper]', function toUpper() {
  this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: `upper` is not a valid attribute, instead you should use `data-upper` instead. The main reason behind using text-transform in CSS alongside something like this is so that the user doesn't see it get converted from lower to uppercase. Your function is also anonymous, there's no point in giving it a name :)

Answer (score 0):

Here we use **onkeyup** event in input field which triggered when the user releases a Key. And here we change our value to uppercase by **toUpperCase()** function.

Note that, **text-transform="Uppercase"** will only change the text in style. but not it's value. So,In order to change value, Use this inline code that will show as well as change the value

`<input id="test-input" type="" name="" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">`

Here is the code snippet that proved the value is change

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="get" action="">
  <input id="test-input" type="" name="" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">
  <input type="button" name="" value="Submit" onclick="checking()">
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function checking(argument) {
   // body...
   var x = document.getElementById("test-input").value
   alert(x);
  }
  
  
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Javascript has a `toUpperCase()` method. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toUpperCase.asp

So wherever you think best to put it in your code, you would have to do something like

```
$(".keywords").val().toUpperCase()
```

Comment: How would I do this for the Course call only??

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do it. Quickest and easiest is just put it inside of case for "course".

Comment: How do I do this for:                  case 'course': 
                     phppage = 'course';
                     ext = '.php?cID=';
                     break;

Comment: Sorry Im a bit confused how to implement it (as basic as it is)

Answer (score -1):

```
**JAVA SCRIPT**
<html>
<body>
<script>
function @ToCaps(obj)
{
obj.value=obj.value.toUpperCase();
}
</script>
<input type="text" onkeyup=@ToCaps(this)"/>
</body>
</html>

**ASP.NET**
Use a css style on the text box, write css like this:
```

.ToCaps { text-transform: uppercase; }

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="ToCaps"></asp:Te writxtBox>

**OR**
simply write this code in textbox
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="text-transform:uppercase"></asp:TextBox>


 **1.Note you don't get intelligence until you type up to style="**
```

Comment: It is never ever going to work this way with `<script type="text/css">`

Answer (score -1):

you can try this
HTML

```
<input id="pan" onkeyup="inUpper()" />
```

javaScript

```
function _( x ) {
  return document.getElementById( x );
}
  // convert text in upper case
  function inUpper() {
    _('pan').value = _('pan').value.toUpperCase();
  }
```