# Css capitalize won't affect in http-post

Tags: css, post, capitalize

I noticed that when I capitalize with css `text-transform:capitalize;` and send this input with an http-post to another page, it won't affect the value for this form-element.

1. Why ?
2. Is there a workaround for it without using php's `ucwords()` ?

Comment: What's wrong using `ucwords()`?

Comment: CSS will only affect the display of the value, not the text value itself. Why don't you just capitalize on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers, in brief:

1. Because CSS changes only the *presentation* of the data, *not* the underlying data itself.
2. Not that I can think of. Unless you're willing to use JavaScript to capitalize individual words prior to form submission?

If, however, you're willing to use JavaScript:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form'),
    input = form.getElementById('input');

function capitalizeInput(elem){
    var inputString = elem.value;
    var capitalizedString = inputString.replace(/(\b[a-z])/g, function(char){return char.toUpperCase();});
    return capitalizedString;
}

form.onsubmit = function(){
    this.value = capitalizeInput(input);
    return false;
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A3ehn/).

This is, obviously, a much simplified demonstration of the capabilities, but is, I think, enough to get you started, albeit only if you intend to go this route. And, if you do, remember that you ***must validate on the server-side too***.

References:

- [Mozilla Developer Network RegExp page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 2):

1) You are styling the content, not modifying it.
2) PHP's `ucwords()` is there to be used, is it not? ;)

Answer (score 1):

CSS will only affect the **display** of the value, not the text value itself.

Why don't you just capitalize on the server side?

If you **must** do this on the client end, see this question for ideas:

[Change Input to Upper Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757101/change-input-to-upper-case)