# how to convert input text to uppercase while typing using javascript

Tags: javascript

In Below code, I want to change the input field to uppercase dynamically i.e. while entering the letters.
I know the style option i.e. **text-transform** but I want to do it using javascript.
I am practicing javascript concepts and as a part of learning, I want to do it.

```
<html>
<body>

  <input type="text" size="40" id="name" name="name">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "In Below code I want to..." Did you forgot to add the code?

Comment: You are better off using the CSS and when they are done typing (onchange) do the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

```
var upCase = getElementById('id').value.toUpperCase();
document.getElementById('id').value = upCase;
```

I believe you can just call the `.toUpperCase()` function on the innerHTML of the class or id you are trying to select. If you are using a class you can use `.getElementsByClassName()`.

Edit:
I missed onKeyUp, this: `onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"`
should work if you only want to use this in the one place.

Comment: and of course this should be called onKeyup or something, so that it always occurs, once a user types text

Comment: Yes, could you just do it this way? onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" as an attribute?

Comment: This won't work very well. If you are typing in the middle of the text the cursor will jump to the end every time you type a letter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look the following post

> [Change Input to Upper Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757101/change-input-to-upper-case)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine onkeyup event:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

With toUpperCase method:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
        $("#input , #textarea").on('input', function(evt) {
          var input = $(this);
          var start = input[0].selectionStart;
          $(this).val(function (_, val) {
            return val.toUpperCase();
          });
          input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = start;
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/22Jap/

Answer (score 0):

```
Actually I got the answer but i dint found any answer like this thats why I have asked this question.
Thanks for your reply guys..

Below is the answer: 


<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <input type="text" size="40" id="name" oninput="convertToUpperCase()">
    <!-- Vishal Biradar-->
    <script>

        function convertToUpperCase(){
            var name=document.getElementById("name").value;   
        if(name!=""){
           name=name.toUpperCase();
           }
        document.getElementById("name").value=name;

        }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: FYI: That is going to make the cursor jump

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why there is no answer here. 
There is a css that answers your question

```
text-transform: uppercase
```

You just need to add that style to your text input.

```
<input type="text" name="LastName" style="text-transform: uppercase;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function converttoUpperCase(e)
{
 var pPosition = e.target.selectionStart;
 e.target.value=e.target.value.toUpperCase();
 e.target.selectionStart=pPosition;
 e.target.selectionEnd=pPosition;
}

function checkOnInput(e)
{
 if(hasLowerCase(e.target.value))
   converttoUpperCase(e);
}

function hasLowerCase(str)
{
 return (/[a-z]/.test(str));
}
```

```html
<input oninput="checkOnInput(event);" type="text" size="40" id="name" name="name">
```