# mb_strtoupper on a Laravel form with Blade Template

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to use the PHP `mb_strtoupper` function on a form, but the parameter of the function does not appear in my form. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" value="{{mb_strtoupper(trans('nome'))}}" class="form-control @error('nome') is-invalid @enderror" />
```

How do I pass the `name` parameter of the form correctly to the `mb_strtoupper` function?

Comment: Did you mean this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757101/change-input-to-upper-case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has a build-in fonction to uppercase strings, it does use mb_strtoupper().

```
<input type="text" name="nome" value="{{ \illuminate\Support\str::upper(__('nome')) }}" class="form-control @error('nome') is-invalid @enderror" />
```

I think your problem is not the uppercase function but the lang() function. You should call the file name then a point then the name of the string key.

```
<input type="text" name="nome" value="{{ \illuminate\Support\str::upper(trans('message.nome')) }}" class="form-control @error('nome') is-invalid @enderror" />
```

[trans() Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/localization#basic-usage)

Comment: Thanks for help, @David! XD