# How to force shiny input to be capitalized

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have found a few javascript functions that transform input text into capitalized text ([here](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/input-field-uppercase/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757101/change-input-to-upper-case)). But I am unsure how to apply the javascript function to shiny inputs. See below I've included an example  selectizeInput function.

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
                
                fluidRow(
                    column(6,
                           selectizeInput("input", "Input words here", 
                                          choices = NULL, 
                                          multiple = TRUE, 
                                          options = list(create = TRUE)),
                           column(6,
                                  textOutput("test"))
)
    )
        )

server <- function(input, output) {
    
output$test<-renderText({input$input})
    
}
```

Comment: Do you want to capitalise text as you type, or capitalise in `outpu$test` after adding?

Comment: PS. Capitalising after adding can be simply done with `renderText(toupper(input$input))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `TRUE`, you can use a JavaScript function for the `create` option, which processes the input:

```
createOption <- "
function(input, callback) {
  var item = input.toUpperCase();
  callback({value: item, label: item});
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = "bootstrap.css",
  
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
           selectizeInput(
             "input", "Input words here", 
             choices = NULL, 
             multiple = TRUE, 
             options = list(
               create = I(createOption)
             )
           )
    ),
    column(6,
           textOutput("test")
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to observe the change in the input and update it with the capitalized value:

```
library(shiny)

ui <-
    fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
              fluidRow(
                column(6,
                       selectizeInput("input", "Input words here", 
                                      choices = NULL, 
                                      multiple = TRUE, 
                                      options = list(create = TRUE)),
                       column(6,textOutput("test"))
                    ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$input,{
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "input",
                         choices = tools::toTitleCase(input$input),
                         selected = tools::toTitleCase(input$input))
    })
    
    output$test<-renderText({input$input})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]